# How to repeatedly read to and from files and erase their contents occasionally?

Tags: c++, file-io

I have 4 files I declare as fstream, File1, File2, File3, File4; I open a separate data.txt file that contains 120 ints and read its contents into file1. Then I have to read the contents of file1 into an array size 20, sort it then write that to file3, then do it again and write to file4. So at this point file3 and file4 each contain 3 blocks of 20 sorted ints and file1 still contains the original 120 ints. Now I have to mergesort file3 and file4 but only 20 elements can enter the memory at one time. Up to this point everything is working well. My problem is that I have to write the mergesort contents back into file1 and file2. File1 is already open and I cant just close it then reopen it, I have to clear the contents of file1 so it is an empty file before I can write back to it.  This is part of a school lab but our teacher told us to just google file manipulation. Me and a few other kids and the computer lab tutors can't seem to get it working right.

Comment: Why can't you close and reopen it? Once you close it you can reopen it with the `std::ios::trunc` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If your not required to use `fstream` you could use `freopen`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  char filename[] = "file1";
  freopen( filename, "r", stdin ); // File content can be read from stdin

  int array[20];
  for(int i=0; i < 20; ++i) {
    cin >> array[i]; // Reads from the file
  }

  freopen( filename, "w", stdout ); // Changes the access to file to write and clears the file 

  // Perform merge .....
  cout << array[0] << endl; // print only to the file

  // ......
  fclose (stdout);
  return 0;
 }
```